# toolbar in bootstrap to link with pagination

Tags: python, django

i have a toolbar that has option of dropdown menu ,and in that dropdown four types of lists are available like list 12, list16, list 32, listall.....

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active in " id="myTabDrop1"  aria-labelledby="dropdown1-tab">
        {% include 'collection12.html' %}   </div>
```

like this files are included in this dropdown menu

Question is how can i use pagination init....
like i have done seperate pagination but i want to link this dropdown with pagination,,,Can any one help me ...??

Comment: Pagination to respect this list setting and paginate according to value set i.e. 12, 16, 32, all? Is this what you want?

Comment: i am a beginner 
yes..like if list 12 is selected than pagination shows 1-12 ....

Comment: If you are using Django's `ListView` then this is exactly what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716270/dynamic-pagination-using-generic-listview. If you are using function based views even then same approach will be used.

Comment: i have tried this ,i am using django's ListView but 
still confused :(

Comment: Add what you tried to the question, the `ListView` part, the template form part, and the javascript part mentioned in the answer to question that I linked earlier.