# Django: use querystring inside a template

Tags: django, listview, request

I'm setting the page size of a ListView following this answer: [Dynamic pagination using Generic ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716270/dynamic-pagination-using-generic-listview)

Now I'm creating an include so I can use in other pages. For that I want the selected option to come selected when the page gets reloaded. To do that I want to use the paginate_by in the querystring inside my template. How Can I do that? I have tried `request.GET["paginate_by"]`, `request.GET("paginate_by")` and so far I didn't find how to do it.

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found it:

```
<select name="paginate_by">
    <option {% if request.GET.paginate_by == "10" %}selected{% endif %}>10</option>
    <option {% if request.GET.paginate_by == "25" %}selected{% endif %}>25</option>
    <option {% if request.GET.paginate_by == "50" %}selected{% endif %}>50</option>
    <option {% if request.GET.paginate_by == "100" %}selected{% endif %}>100</option>
</select>
```